# Android Background Location Limitations

Tags: android, google-api, android-location

I'm using the FusedLocationApi to build an app that tracks users. I've read the background limitations that apply to Android Oreo and for that purpose I'm using a foreground service to keep tracking real-time. I noticed than on devices that run an Android version older than Oreo, location updates are triggered only a few times each hour. In the case of older Android versions I don't start a foreground service.

Does the location background limitation apply to all devices? Has anybody seen something similar?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get the answer or fix for this